# How to uninstall Cloud SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, uninstallation, credentials, gsutil, fedora-25

First I installed stand-alone gsutil on Fedora 25, it ran nice for months.
Then I installed Cloud SDK, and my Google Cloud credentials have been broken ever since.

I don't need Cloud SDK after all.  I just want to use gsutil again.
Is there a way to uninstall Cloud SDK and credentials from Linux?
Or maybe uninstall all Google Cloud products and reinstall the stand-alone gsutil?

Comment: Linux is a kernel. It has no idea what kind of package manager, if any, the OS uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To explain the likely reason this is happening:**

When you install the Cloud SDK, it takes some steps to make sure that when you type `gsutil` from the shell, it resolves to the Cloud SDK version (depending on the installation method, it might make some executable scripts in `/usr/local/bin/`, or put `/path/to/cloud/sdk/bin` at the front of your PATH environment variable). This Cloud SDK wrapper script for gsutil does some extra auth logic, loading an extra .boto file which contains credentials produced from running `gcloud auth login`. You can see this extra .boto file when running `gcloud version -l`:

```
$ gsutil version -l
[...]
using cloud sdk: True
config path(s): /home/USER/.boto, /home/USER/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/USER@gmail.com/.boto
[...]
```

It's likely that the auth credentials in that extra .boto file are overriding the credentials in your `$HOME/.boto` file.

**How to use standalone gsutil again:**

You'll need to ensure that the first `gsutil` your shell finds is the standalone version. This essentially means that the directory containing the standalone gsutil executable should come before the cloud sdk directory in your PATH environment variable. This can be done via prepending it to your PATH variable, via adding something like this to the end of your .bashrc file:

```
if [ -d "/path/to/standalone/gsutil/directory" ]; then
  PATH="/path/to/standalone/gsutil/directory:$PATH"
fi
```

After doing this, you can run this command to reload your .bashrc file and check the "using cloud sdk" value of your gsutil info:

```
$ source "$HOME/.bashrc"; gsutil version -l
```

If this still shows that you're using the Cloud SDK version of gsutil, you might have an alias defined for gsutil - you can check for this by running:

```
$ type gsutil
```

If you still encounter auth issues when using the standalone version of gsutil, you'll need to generate new credentials:

```
$ gsutil config
```

Comment: Thanks mhouglum.  Adding your conditional to the end of the .bashrc file worked like a charm.